# How to get the height of a (scroll)view including masked area

Tags: android

I need to print the view (a form the user is filling) to a PDFDocument (to send by email). For that, I need to get the view's height to setup the PFDDocument.

When using view.getHeight or view.getMeasuredHeight, it does not include masked content, but only the visible area.

This is my current code :

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.scrollView_affiche);
Integer v_height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
Integer v_width = view.getMeasuredWidth();

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(v_width,v_height , 1).create();
```

Comment: The size of a ScrollView is only as big as you see it on screen.  Are you actually trying to measure the size of its child view, which may have offscreen parts?

Comment: @DougStevenson My scrollview contains a single LinearLayout. I gonna try printing this (child) view instead of the scrollview.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I indeed needed to print its child view instead odfthe scrollview. Would you please post as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the child view of the ScrollView instead of the ScrollView itself:

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView_affiche);
View child = sv.getChildAt(0);  // or find it by id
int height = child.getHeight();
int width = child.getWidth();
```